# How to store date in GAE datastore in a programmatic way using Java and performing queries on dates?

Tags: java, date, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a use case where I need to fetch data from a source and it contains different columns including dates. Initially, I stored the dates as a string itself, but now onwards I need to perform querying operations on "date" property as well.

I am accepting the date format for the date to be stored from the user before importing the data which also is in string format.

I would want to know, how can I convert "date" data coming from the data source to the format supported by GAE datastore and not only store but how will I be able to apply queries like "select * from database where date > some_date;"

To accept the date for the querying purpose, I am using bootstrap "Date Range Picker".

Please suggest.

Comment: GAE datastore natively supports Dates, you don't need to convert to String or anything else

Comment: Thanks @IgorArtamonov, but my incoming data source is in string format, do I need to convert it into "Date" in my Java code and then put that entity in the datastore?

Comment: Sure. Everything it coming as strings through http protocol, but you convert numbers to int/long, dates to Date, and so on. You aren't forced to use string everywhere just because http request gives you that

Comment: Thanks, I will do that, but how will I query to get the results as explained in the above question, the user will enter the date from the Bootstrap DateRange Picker, is there any preformatting before applying queries to the datastore to apply queries on the Dates?

Comment: just use Date for query too

Comment: If you just need the dates and not the time you could also store your dates as string with the following format YYYYMMDD. In such a way you would be able to easily apply a filter to your objectify Query.